# Fit my page with screen at zoom-out or zoom-in

Tags: html, css, zooming

Sorry if my tone is not good!
Here is my HTML and CSS code.
**CSS:**

```
 #home article {
background: url(../images/top_bg.png) repeat;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 0px;
border: solid 7px #FFFFFF;
width: 99%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <section id="home" data-speed="10" data-type="background" style="background-position: 50% 0px;">
---- Some Code to display ---        

</section>
```

**Question:** My question is this : When I zoom-in or zoom-out with (ctrl,- or ctrl,+), my page should remain fit with screen. No horizontal Scroll bar should appear.

HERE is example page: Zoom in and zoom out to understand my question. http://jenslehmann.com/#/ambassador

Comment: I also want scrollbar should not display at my website at zoom like Jens Lehmann website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below in your css:

```
.background { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; height: 200%; left: -50%; position: fixed; width: 200%;}

.background img{ bottom: 0; display: block; left: 0; margin: auto; min-height: 50%; min-width: 50%; right: 0; top: 0;}
```